# How do I use different themes for open street maps in open layers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openmaptiles

I have a map application with custom interactive layers, but I want to use the dark theme from [this](https://openmaptiles.org/styles/). I'm using [playing around on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ju86qb17/) and I just can't seen to get the dark theme to work. I tried this:

```
      new TileLayer({
        source: new TileJSON({
          url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openmaptiles/dark-matter-gl-style/master/style.json'
        })
      })
```

I'm using classic apache and php. I have no clue about npm and webpack.

Comment: We are the authors of OpenMapTiles project and the repos you are linking. If you need to use the dark-matter-gl style - the easiest is to go to https://cloud.maptiler.com/maps/darkmatter/, create a free account and copy&paste the sample viewer provided on this website. This gives you free hosting and the style into your webpage - with a viewer of your choice, including OpenLayers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `style.json` is only a Mapbox Style Specification, not the Data as TileJSON itself.

You can use Mapbox Style Specifications for Vector Tile Layers like the OSM by using [ol-mapbox-style](https://github.com/openlayers/ol-mapbox-style). There is also some information about this issue [on openmaptiles, where you found the theme.](https://openmaptiles.org/docs/website/openlayers/)

Comment: I have no clue how to use `ol-mapbox-style`. They seem to assume you're using `npm` and `webpack`, I don't use either.  I'm using classic apache and php.

Comment: Thx for sharing the fiddle! unpkg.com is a great tool for using modern software in classic environments